# how do you modify styled data frame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I have this data frame:

```
df

Server        Env.    Model   Percent_Utilized
server123     Prod     Cisco.       50
server567.    Prod     Cisco.       80
serverabc.    Prod     IBM.         100
serverdwc.    Prod     IBM.         45
servercc.     Prod      Hitachi.    25
Avg                                60

server123Uat  Uat     Cisco.       40
server567u    Uat     Cisco.       30
serverabcu    Uat     IBM.         80
serverdwcu    Uat     IBM.         45
serverccu     Uat     Hitachi      15
Avg                               42
```

I have style applied to this df as follows:

```
def color(val):
    if val > 80:
        color = 'red'
    elif val > 50 and val <= 80:
        color = 'yellow'
    else:
        color = 'green'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color

df_new = df.style.applymap(color, subset=["Percent_Utilized"])
```

I need to add % at the end of the numbers on Percent_Utilized columns:

resulting data frame need to look something like this:

```
df_new

    Server        Env.    Model   Percent_Utilized
    server123     Prod     Cisco.       50%
    server567.    Prod     Cisco.       80%
    serverabc.    Prod     IBM.         100%
    serverdwc.    Prod     IBM.         45%
    servercc.     Prod      Hitachi.    25%
    Avg                                60%
    
    server123Uat  Uat     Cisco.       40%
    server567u    Uat     Cisco.       30%
    serverabcu    Uat     IBM.         80%
    serverdwcu    Uat     IBM.         45%
    serverccu     Uat     Hitachi      15%
    Avg                               42%
```

when I do this:

```
df_new['Percent_Utilized'] = df_new['Percent_Utilized'].astype(str) + '%'
```

I get this error:

TypeError: 'Styler" object is not suscriptable.

Comment: You might consider renaming your `df_new` variable to `styler` or `styled_df` since it's a [Styler](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html) object and no longer a DataFrame. I find that can be helpful in making it clear it's *not* a DataFrame so those methods aren't going to work as expected.

Comment: More relevant to your question, I believe you're looking for [format](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html#pandas-io-formats-style-styler-format) `df.style.applymap(...).format(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df.style` returns a `pd.Styler` object, not a `pd.DataFrame` object. So you cannot use `.astype`. You can use [`Styler.format`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html) like this:

```
df_new = df.style.applymap(color, subset=["Percent_Utilized"])\
           .format('{:.0f}%', subset=['Percent_Utilized'], na_rep='nan')
```

You'd get something like this, ignore the `Avg` rows as they are not read properly by `read_clipboard`:

[image]

Comment: this works on the Jupyter notebook. But when I try to write this df_new to excel, % signs are not written to the excel spreadsheet any ideas?

Comment: Probably because when you open an excel file, it (Excel) automatically parses `50%` as a number. Also, if your final destination is excel, you can forget about `.format` and do `df_new.to_excel('file.xlsx', float_format='{:.0f}%'` as shown in [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.to_excel.html).

Comment: I get incomplete format error.